# Which dbghelp.dll do I use for debugging?

Tags: windows-7, debug

I'm trying to configure symbols in Process Explorer. I have the Windows SDK installed (and thus, Debugging Tools). However, there are two versions of dbghelp.dll -- x86 and x64.

Which one do I use? Other sources on the net say to just point to the dbghelp.dll that's in the base directory of the Debugging Tools. But there's no such dbghelp.dll -- they're in their respect 32 and 64 bit folders (i.e., `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x64`).

I'm using a Windows 7 x64 operating system, so does that mean I should load the x64 .dll? Or is it a matter of what I'm debugging?

If it is a matter of what I'm debugging, does that mean that I have to switch this .dll depending what process I want to get symbol information on in Process Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on 64 bit Windows, use the x64 version (ProcExp extracts an x64 version at runtime so it needs the x64 Version of the DLL).

Comment: I was just about to post that through trial and error, ProcMon/ProcExp wouldn't accept the 32bit .dll, only the x64 one. Thanks for the help!